# What is the best/most efficient way to facilitate the appending of a label property to each object inside an array, inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

## Problem Overview:

I'm trying to add labels to values inside an array property of an object.

> The objects are various *Insights* fetched from **Facebook's Graph API**. We pull 25 different metrics...

There are 3 in particular that I am interested in.
My search criteria: `name = 'page_content_activity'`,  `period = 'day'/'week'/'days_28'`

Here is an example of an object returned from the search:

```js
{
  name: 'page_content_activity',
  period: 'day',
  values: [
    {
      value: 23168,
      end_time: '2020-03-10T07:00:00+0000',
    },
    {
      value: 19309,
      end_time: '2020-03-11T07:00:00+0000',
    },
  ],
  title: 'Daily Page Stories',
  description: 'Daily: The number of stories created about your Page. (Total Count)',
  id: 'PAGE_ID/insights/page_content_activity/day',
}
```

---

## Objective

The labels I want to add to object in `values` are 'Today' and 'Yesterday' giving me:

```js
{
...
  values: [
    {
      value: 23168,
      end_time: '2020-03-10T07:00:00+0000',
      label: 'Today'
    },
    {
      value: 19309,
      end_time: '2020-03-11T07:00:00+0000',
      label: 'Yesterday'
    },
  ],
...
}
```

I want to repeat this process with each of the other two time periods 'week' and 'days_28' with the labels to be added 'This Week', 'Last Week' and 'Last 28 Days', 'Previous 28 Days' respectively.

---

## My Solution:

1. I created the below array of nested arrays each with the `period` value **first** to be used in the search and another array of the two labels to be added

```js
const periods = [
  ['day', ['Today', 'Yesterday']],
  ['week', ['This Week', 'Last Week']],
  ['days_28', ['Last 28 Days', 'Prev 28 Days']],
]
```

2. Here is my function to find the objects, append the labels, and then render the list items:

```js
const PageStats = ({ insights, page }) => {
  if (!page && !insights) return

  // This is the function in question
  const renderActivity = () => {
    const name = 'page_content_activity'
    let activity = []
    periods.forEach(period => {
      let data = insights.data.find(insight => {
        return insight.name === name && insight.period === period[0]
      })
      // Here is where I am adding the label to each object in 'values' array
      data.values[0].label = period[1][0]
      data.values[1].label = period[1][1]
      activity.push(data.values)
    })
    // Finally I map thru activity array and map thru each period array to 
    // render a list item that displays the newly added label and corresponding value
    return activity.map(period => {
      return period.map(item => renderItem(item))
    })
  }

  return (
    <Segment raised placeholder>
      {renderLabel(`${page.name} - ${page.category}`)}
      <Header content="Total Activity - Over Time" />
      <List horizontal>{renderActivity()}</List>
    </Segment>
  )
}
```

> I know that chaining `map()` is not advised but it's what I came up with that worked and it's a small data set that won't get larger over time...

---

## My Question:

I spent a long time on this and tried different methods for representing the `period` variable and the corresponding labels. I had them in an array but as objects then used `Object.entries(period).map(...` but it started getting ugly and I finally settled on this.

I am curious to see what other solutions are possible? I'd like to know the shortest most efficient method for doing something of this nature. I look forward to seeing your responses!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are three primary pain points that I'd want to address:

1. Minimizing the data search.
2. Removing the double mapping.
3. Deconstructing the arrays for readability.

The first optimization requires modifying your dataset. Your current limitation is that you have two separate keys you're searching. If you can combine them into a single key, you can convert your insights from an array to an object:

```js
insights.data = {
  page_content_activity_day: {
    name: 'page_content_activity',
    period: 'day',
    values: [
      {
        value: 23168,
        end_time: '2020-03-10T07:00:00+0000',
      },
      {
        value: 19309,
        end_time: '2020-03-11T07:00:00+0000',
      },
    ],
    title: 'Daily Page Stories',
    description: 'Daily: The number of stories created about your Page. (Total Count)',
    id: '297134493721424/insights/page_content_activity/day',
  },
  ...
}
```

This would let you remove your `find` method. If you are doing this multiple times, you may also find it to be marginally faster, since you make one loop to create the keys instead of 3 to find them.

The second optimization recognizes that your `forEach` function is creating a 1:1 mapping of periods to objects. Rather than looping twice, one to create objects and one to render them, you can combine the two.

The third optimization is deconstructing your arrays, so you can give meaningful names to your elements.

This results in:

```js
const renderActivity = () => {
  const name = 'page_content_activity'
  return periods.map(([period, [currentLabel, priorLabel]]) => {
    let [currentValue, priorValue] = insights.data[`${name}_${period}`].values
    currentValue.label = currentLabel
    priorValue.label = priorLabel
    return renderItem([currentValue, priorValue])
  }
}
```

I'm recreating the values array in `renderItem`, but this seems a negligible cost for code that feels more readable to me. It could certainly be kept as `values[]`.

If you had created an activities array because you weren't certain there would always be data for a given combination of keys, you could add an `if` condition that returns `null` if values doesn't exist. Your final map will include null values when data doesn't exist, but React will ignore these. That makes it harder to deconstruct the values, which makes me sad, but it would look like:

```js
const renderActivity = () => {
  const name = 'page_content_activity'
  return periods.map(([period, [currentLabel, priorLabel]]) => {
    let values = insights.data[`${name}_${period}`]?.values

    if (!values) {
      return null
    }

    values[0].label = currentLabel
    values[1].label = priorLabel
    return renderItem(values)
  }
}
```

(The [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) allows you to get undefined instead of an error if the underlying object is undefined.)

Comment: thank you for the input! So with regards to modifying my dataset, that may be possible to do in my reducer after fetching the data from FB, but will likely result in breaking changes throughout the app. So that might not be an option worth pursuing, since the function to do so would likely negate any performance improvements.
I have, however, edited my question to clarify from whence the data comes. 
I will indeed look into the `optional chaining operator` to help mitigate errors from undefined underlying objects.

Comment: Another option might be adding another field to your data store, which maps the combined key to the array index. Then it would look something like `values = insights.data[insights.indexMap[`${name}_${period}`]]`. Adding the entry to the map would be an additional line as you grab your graph data. The main thing to look for in this kind of optimization is, can I reduce the number of branches I need to deal with? With find(), you've got a true/false condition to manage. In a map, you set the entry, then you retrieve the entry. It's a straight-line flow.

Answer (score 2):

1) Build `periodsObject` so that can avoid multiple `find` calls

2) Use `filter` and `map` methods to simplify the required output.

```js
const insights = [
  {
    name: "page_content_activity",
    period: "day",
    values: [
      {
        value: 23168,
        end_time: "2020-03-10T07:00:00+0000"
      },
      {
        value: 19309,
        end_time: "2020-03-11T07:00:00+0000"
      }
    ],
    title: "Daily Page Stories",
    description:
      "Daily: The number of stories created about your Page. (Total Count)",
    id: "297134493721424/insights/page_content_activity/day"
  }
];

const periods = [
  ["day", ["Today", "Yesterday"]],
  ["week", ["This Week", "Last Week"]],
  ["days_28", ["Last 28 Days", "Prev 28 Days"]]
];

const renderItem = item => console.log(item);

const periodsObject = Object.fromEntries(periods);

const renderActivity = () => {
  const name = "page_content_activity";
  return insights
    .filter(
      insight =>
        insight.name === name &&
        Object.keys(periodsObject).includes(insight.period)
    )
    .map(insight => ({
      ...insight,
      values: insight.values.map((value, i) =>
        renderItem({ ...value, label: periodsObject[insight.period][i] })
      )
    }));
};

renderActivity();
```